# Creating a Python guessing game

Tags: python

I am new to Python, so I decided to start with a numbers game. I have my numbers being input correctly, but I would like it to display the number of correct answers and the correct original, random numbers.

Code as follows:

```
import random
print('============================')
print('Now try to guess a list of numbers! The range of number is 0-10')
print('How many numbers do you want?')

numberOfNumbers = int(input('Enter the number: '))
counter = 0
answers = [random.randint(0, 10), numberOfNumbers]
values = []
numCorrect = 0

print('Enter your ' + str(numberOfNumbers) + ' numbers.')

while numberOfNumbers != counter:
    counter += 1
    values.append(int(input("Enter number " + str(counter) + ": ")))
    if values == answers:
        numCorrect += 1
        print('You got' + numCorrect + ' correct!')

print('Original: ' + str(answers))
print('Your guess: ' + str(values))
```

Current output:

```
Now try to guess a list of numbers! The range of number is 0-10
How many numbers do you want?
Enter the number: 3
Enter your 3 numbers.
Enter number 1: 1
Enter number 2: 2
Enter number 3: 3
Original: [5, 3]
Your guess: [1, 2, 3]
```

Target Output:

```
Now try to guess a list of numbers! The range of number is 0-10
How many numbers do you want?
Enter the number: 3
Enter your 3 numbers.
Enter number 1: 1
Enter number 2: 2
Enter number 3: 3
(Currently not working for print) You got (x) Correct!
(Here prints answers, it's only printing two numbers) Original: [5, 3, x]
(Your input prints here, working as planned) Your guess: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: So what's the *problem* with what you've written? `answers = [random.randint(0, 10), numberOfNumbers]` looks pretty suspect, but what's the unexpected outcome?

Comment: Use a for loop, w3Schools will give you a good description on how they work. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Answer (score 0):

You do this:

```
values.append(int(input("Enter number " + str(counter) + ": ")))
    if values == answers:
        numCorrect += 1
```

But, since you keep appending to `values`, it will never be equal to (`==`) `answers` until all the correct answers are in there, and even then only if they are in the correct order.

If you want `numCorrect` to have the number of answers in `values` that is currently correct, you can write something like:

```
numCorrect = len([v for v in values if v in answers])
```

Of course, if you *only* want to print `numCorrect` if it *changes*, you have a bit more code to write.

(also note that this goes sideways if you have duplicate correct answers, so it's not quite this simple, but I'm not writing your game, just correcting your code so it does what you appear to want it to do)

You do this:

```
answers = [random.randint(0, 10), numberOfNumbers]
```

That creates a list with two numbers, a random number and `numberOfNumbers`. It looks like you really want a list of length `numberOfNumbers` with all random numbers:

```
answers = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(numberOfNumbers)]
```

This could include duplicates, but you get to figure out how to avoid that.

In general, I would recommend using a free IDE like PyCharm or Spyder to debug your code. They have options that allow you to *step* through your code one line at a time, so you can see how the values of variables change as your commands execute - that will make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pretty new to python I decided to stick to your code and correct them instead of complicating it. So, what you basically did wrong was that you were using `print('You got ' + str(numCorrect) + ' correct!')` inside the `if statement` because if the condition wasn't true the print statement wouldn't work.

The next was that you needed to get the random numbers inside while loop to get the `x` number of random numbers. Or, else what you were doing was that you simply got one random number and the input from `numberOfNumbers`.

Here's the final code:

```
import random
print('============================')
print('Now try to guess a list of numbers! The range of number is 0-10')
print('How many numbers do you want?')

numberOfNumbers = int(input('Enter the number: '))
counter = 0
answers = []
values = []
numCorrect = 0

print('Enter your ' + str(numberOfNumbers) + ' numbers.')

while numberOfNumbers != counter:
    ans_var = random.randint(0,10)
    answers.append(ans_var)
    counter += 1
    values.append(int(input("Enter number " + str(counter) + ": ")))
    if values == answers:
        numCorrect += 1
print('You got ' + str(numCorrect) + ' correct!')
print('Original: ' + str(answers))
print('Your guess: ' + str(values))
```

Hope it helps :)